# Grid поток элементов

Tags: html, css, grid

Как изменить поток элементов в грид, так чтобы заполнение шло не:

```
1  2
3  4
5  6
```

А было вот таким:

```
1  4
2  5
3  6
```

UPD: Можно использовать свойства и на дочерних элементах, но чтобы все было автоматизировано при добавлении конетнта.

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это:

```
  ul {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-auto-flow: column;
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я знаю про это, нужно чтобы еще строки(ряды) автоматически добавлялись при добавлении контента, в общем чтобы поведение было как у простого грида, но поток заполнения другой.